# Android: how to make the ListView stay disabled even after the apps closed

Tags: java, android, listview

[image]

The 2nd note is disabled i want to make it stay as it is even the app was closed. I wasn't sure if sharedpreferences will work, anyway this is how I disabled the listview item..

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                    .setMessage("Do you want to lock this note?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if(listView.getChildAt(position).isEnabled())
                            {
                                listView.getChildAt(position).setEnabled(false);
                            }
                            saveData();
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Yamete!",null).show();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Note: the listview was in a fragment, all I want to accomplish is simply to save the disabled state ot the listview item.

Comment: add a boolean `isDisabled` and save the value in the `setOnItemLongClick` and the next time the list is loaded check those value

Comment: can you elaborate the instruction more? sorry im still a beginner at android and still not familliar enough with it thanks

Comment: just add a new member variable, `isDisabled`, to the class representing the data for the list and set the value to true, ie `isDisabled = true` in your `OnItemLongClickListener` and in your adapter, use the value of `isDisabled` to determine the wether the current entity to be disabled or not

Comment: what about the position of the specific listview item?

Comment: that shouldn't be a problem, its already a parameter  passed in the`OnItemLongClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

You can save a list of the disabled items, or a list of all items in a db or shared preferences, easiest way for that is using Hawk https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk which is a library that can easily store any type of data in shared preferences

Comment: i tried this one and still cannot include the supposed to be value "T" which is.. listView.getChildAt(position).setEnabled(false); im clueless on how to use this library

Comment: does this save the instance of the listview? when i put the listview as the "T" value, the app just kept on crashing

Comment: I would save a list of the positions that need to be disabled, not the list view